# Html + CSS - header & text

Tags: html, css, text

I'm new to html/CSS starting a few weeks ago and I decided work on my first template for my little gaming network and got a issue. The problem is I have a ideal header but when I do CSS for text over a header nothing shows up and the header is covering the text no matter what I do.

[image: header preview]

This how I would like have it + white text over it .

```css
#header .h-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/OW0YQWa.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.h-bg:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Next time include your `html` as well as `css`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to achieve a dark transparent bar that overlaps a background, you were close. You were setting the height to 100% in more than one way.

However, this is probably not the best way to go about it.

```css
#header .h-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/OW0YQWa.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.h-bg:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="h-bg">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need the dark transparent bar to be the navigation, you shouldn't use pseudo elements for it. Instead, a set of `div` elements is all you need.

```css
#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/OW0YQWa.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.h-bg{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
}

.h-bg ul{list-style: none;}
.h-bg ul li{display: inline-block; padding: 0 10px;}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="h-bg">
    <ul>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```